# csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC does not work with float in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a dataframe in Python that I want to save as a CSV with this line:

```
df.to_csv(PATH, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, index = False)
```

The dataframe has this form:

```
date          timeOfDay    GridID            score
2015-12-31     Morning      1445            0.000000
```

And the result after that piece of code is:

```
date,timeOfDay,GridID,score
"2015-01-01","Morning",1445,"0.0"
```

But I don't understand why score is quoted when the code has `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` while it is a `numpy.float64`. Indeed, `GridID` is stored successfully.

EDIT: 
If only score is stored in the csv file and anything else, the values are float, not quoted. Only if I add just a column then score is quoted again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug already on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12922). So you're actually not doing anything wrong.

Quoting the relevant part from the bug description:

> The problem is that `pandas.core.internals.FloatBlock.to_native_types` (and by extension `pandas.formats.format.FloatArrayFormatter.get_result_as_array`) unconditionally formats the float array to a str array, which is then passed unchanged to the csv module and hence will be wrapped in quotes by that code.

This is marked as closed and will probably be fixed in a near future release (specifically [Next Major Release](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/milestone/32)).